# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_get_xf_index'

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Getting error "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_get_xf_index'" while writing from array

Tried a lot of recommendation from Google, but nothing seems to work for me.

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Report.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})

# Adjust the column width.
worksheet.set_column(15, 15, 15, 15)

# Write some data headers.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Name', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'Description', bold)
worksheet.write('C1', 'Products', bold)
worksheet.write('D1', 'Author', bold)

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
data = (
['Test-1', 'Confirms that API can be called with valid parameters.',    'x, y, x', 'Sam'],
['Test-2', 'Confirms that API can be called with valid parameters.', 'x, y, x', 'Sam'],
['Test-3', 'Confirms that API can be called with valid parameters.', 'x, y, x', 'Sam'],
['Test-4', 'Confirms that API can be called with valid parameters.', 'x, y, x', 'Sam'],
)

# Start from the first cell below the headers.
row = 1
col = 0

for name, description, products, author in data:
    worksheet.write_string  (row, col, name)
    worksheet.write_string  (row, col + 1, description)
    worksheet.write_string  (row, col + 2, products)
    worksheet.write_string  (row, col + 3, author)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Error Messages :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\VCI_TESTSUITES\rt-testsuite-working\rt-testsuite-tests\Data\Tests\ProcessingPrograms\XMLReportGenerator - Copy.py", line 38, in <module>
    workbook.close()
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 311, in close
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 674, in _store_workbook
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 135, in _create_package
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\packager.py", line 190, in _write_worksheet_files
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 3772, in _assemble_xml_file
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 5209, in _write_cols
  File "C:\Users\iqs1sba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 5224, in _write_col_info
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_get_xf_index'
```

Comment: Please help me resolve this error. I am new to Python & xlsxwriter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the `set_column` method. You're calling it with the wrong syntax. It's `set_column(self, first_col, last_col, width=None, cell_format=None, options=None)`

In your case, that would be

```py
worksheet.set_column(0, 3, 15)
```

Comment: Wow, I just tried that and it worked like magic. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: I am trying to understand the numbers. self = 0, first_col = 3, last_col = 15. 0 I understood, but 3 & 15. Please give me a little for information.

Comment: `self` is not an actual parameter that you need to pass, it's just a keyword to reference class instance. So, it's `first_col = 0, last_col = 3, width = 15`

Comment: I see. Thank you.